# Centering of a div, but the normal CSS does not work

Tags: css

I want to center a div, but the general way is

```
#selector{position:relative;margin:0px auto;}
```

What exactly is wrong below

```
#crp{top:40%; position:absolute; margin:auto;}
```

The Div below is not nested but a standalone.  The #crp is going to the extreme right.

```
<div id="crp">...something goes here....</div>
```

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because its position is absolute, it does not work according to margins anymore, it is expecting you to fix its position.

Just like you are setting its vertical position with the top property, you have to set its horizontal position as well.

Comment: Try setting the width of your div, as @rochal suggested.

Comment: @soto Its not the contents, text-align, aligns the contents not the whole div.

Answer (score 2):

To center a div using `margin:0 auto;` you **must** specify `width` of the element.

You could also use `text-align:center;` on the parent container.

Also remove any absolute positioning because it breaks standard element flow.

Comment: Its not only text, but images etc.,
#crp is the parent container
specified width:100% does not seem to work though

Comment: <div style="text-align:center;"><img /></div> WILL center align the image as well.

Comment: I want to align the div not the contents